# Write a query to select ENAME(Employee names) who get the highest salaries from their DEPT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, plsql, sql-server-2012

I have created the below table in MSSQLServer & inserted the further rows.

```
(
     EID int,
     ENAME nvarchar(50),
     DEPT nvarchar(50),
     Salary int
)
GO

Insert into Emp11 values (1, 'A','Dev', 60000)
Insert into Emp11 values (2, 'B','Dev', 60000)
Insert into Emp11 values (3, 'C','Support', 60000)
Insert into Emp11 values (4, 'D','Support', 30000)
Insert into Emp11 values (5, 'E','Reporting', 30000)
Insert into Emp11 values (6, 'F','Reporting', 70000)
Insert into Emp11 values (7, 'G','Reporting', 70000)
Insert into Emp11 values (8, 'H','QA', 70000)
Insert into Emp11 values (9, 'I','QA', 90000)
Insert into Emp11 values (10,'J','QA', 90000
```

I am running this query-

```
select ename, salary, DEPT from(
    select *
        , row_number() over (partition by DEPT order by salary desc) as rn
    from EMP11
)a where rn=1

--Result->
ename  salary   DEPT
A      60000    Dev
I      90000    QA
F      70000    Reporting
C      60000    Support
```

I want to get more than 1 ENAME if they get same salary as highest salary from their DEPT, i.e:

```
ENAME   salary  DEPT
A   60000   Dev
B   60000   Dev
I   90000   QA
J   90000   QA
F   70000   Reporting
G   70000   Reporting
C   60000   Support
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rank()`; as opposed to `row_number()`, which guarantees unicity of each number, it assigns the same rank to rows that have the same value:

```
select ename, salary, dept
from (
    select *, rank() over (partition by dept order by salary desc) as rn
    from emp11
) a 
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Yes, its returning the expected results. Thanks for Answering!!